# Multiple / in computation graph names

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it officially OK to use multiple / in names for the computation graph, similar to Linux  file systems, e.g.:

```
    //test1 will point to /test1
    /test1//test4 will point to /test1/test4
```

I have tested and used this for parameters. It does what I expect.

My question is: Is this behaviour guaranteed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10510/multiple-/-in-computation-graph-names/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is a good chance that not all client libraries will catch this.  There are generally libraries in each language to help with constructing names, e.g.

C++:

ros::names::append

Python:

roslib.names.ns_join

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1